# Differentiate between user types

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code which I have been trying to modify for use with two users (bottom half).

What I want to happen is that when a user logs in , their Login_ID is found in the table and then their User_Role_ID is found.

If its 1 it goes to a certain page , if its 2 it goes to another page.

```
 if(count($_POST)>0) {   
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id,Login_ID,Name,User_Role_ID FROM user WHERE Login_ID='" . $_POST["id"] . "' ");
    $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);   
    if(is_array($row)) {   
       $_SESSION["Login_ID"] = $row[Login_ID];   
    } 
    else {      
       echo "Invalid ID!";       
    }    
 }
 if($_SESSION["User_Role_ID"] == "2") {    
    header("Location: home.php");
 }
 else if($_SESSION['User_Role_ID'] == 1) {    
    header("Location: www.google.com");  
 }
```

Comment: `$_SESSION["Login_ID"] = $row[Login_ID];` should be     `$_SESSION["Login_ID"] = $row['Login_ID']; `

Comment: You have `User_ID_Role` (`SELECT id,Login_ID,Name,User_ID_Role FROM...`) in your query, but are checking `User_Role_ID` (`if($_SESSION["User_Role_ID"]) ==...`). Are these supposed to be the same?

Comment: What happens currently? Paths should be absolute.

Comment: This $_SESSION["User_Role_ID"] should be $row["User_Role_ID"]

Comment: Where do you define `$_SESSION["User_Role_ID"]`? Currently you are only setting `$_SESSION["Login_ID"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id,Login_ID,Name,User_ID_Role FROM user WHERE Login_ID='" . $_POST["id"] . "' ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);   
if(is_array($row)) {   
    $_SESSION["Login_ID"] = $row[Login_ID];   
    switch ($row["User_ID_Role"]){    
        case "1": header("Location: www.google.com"); break;
        case "2": header("Location: home.php"); break;   
    }
} 
else {      
    echo "Invalid ID!";       
}
```

Comment: side note: `User_ID_Role` != `User_Role_ID` -> `"SELECT id,Login_ID,Name,User_ID_Role FROM...` && `$row["User_Role_ID"]`. Also, `$row[Login_ID]` should be changed to `$row['Login_ID']` to prevent a `Unknown Constant` warning.

Comment: Great ! , Now if a user gains access to a admin page (2) through a url would I just use if(isset($_SESSION['User_Role_ID'] == 2)) { content }

Comment: That could work. It would be better to use a controller.

Answer (score 0):

You must defined $_SESSION["User_Role_ID"]
and you have an error

```
$_SESSION["Login_ID"] = $row[Login_ID]
```

your code must be:

```
 if(is_array($row)) {   
    $_SESSION["Login_ID"] = $row["Login_ID"];   
    $_SESSION["User_Role_ID"]=$row["User_Role_ID"];
    }
```